# AFNetworking multi part data upload Failure block

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

From the AFNetworking tutorial I am using following code for multi part upload

```
 NSArray *operations = [AFURLConnectionOperation batchOfRequestOperations:mutableOperations progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {
        NSLog(@"%lu of %lu complete", numberOfFinishedOperations, totalNumberOfOperations);
    } completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations)
    {

        NSLog(@"All operations in batch complete");
    } ];
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperations:operations waitUntilFinished:NO];
```

But how will I know the upload is failed or not.? Is there any failure block ?

Answer (score 0):

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager =  [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"file://path/to/image.png"];
[manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
 [formData appendPartWithFileURL:filePath name:@"image" error:nil];
} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: The above code is for uploading one file.I am using multipart form data